# Update fails after removing kernel

Tags: updates, update-manager

I had to remove a new kernel version after Ubuntu refused to boot. Since then the update manager has not been working and I get the following error. How do I get the update manager to work again?

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: All the PPAs mentioned in the error messages should be removed, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get content of repos for xenial Ubuntu distribution (16.04) 
but if you go for example to http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ you can see that xenial is not available for this ppa/. 
Did you system upgrade to 16.04 recently?

It doesn't have anything in common with removal of kernel.